# Querying a Global Secondary Index in dynamodb Local

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I am creating a table and GSI in DynamoDB, using these parameters, as per the documentation:

`configId` is the primary key of the table, and I am using the `publisherId` as the primary key for the GSI. (I've removed some unnecessary configuration parameters for brevity)

```
var params = {
    TableName: 'Configs',
    KeySchema: [ 
        {
            AttributeName: 'configId',
            KeyType: 'HASH',
        }
    ],
    AttributeDefinitions: [
        {
            AttributeName: 'configId',
            AttributeType: 'S',
        },
        {
            AttributeName: 'publisherId',
            AttributeType: 'S',
        }
    ],
    GlobalSecondaryIndexes: [ 
        { 
            IndexName: 'publisher_index', 
            KeySchema: [
                {
                    AttributeName: 'publisherId',
                    KeyType: 'HASH',
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

I am querying this table using this:

```
{ TableName: 'Configs',
  IndexName: 'publisher_index',
  KeyConditionExpression: 'publisherId = :pub_id',
  ExpressionAttributeValues: { ':pub_id': { S: '700' } } }
```

but I keep getting the error:

> "ValidationException: One or more parameter values were invalid: Condition parameter type does not match schema type"

In the docs it specifies that the primary `KeyType` can either be `HASH` or `RANGE`, and that you set the `AttributeType` in the `AttributeDefinitions` field. I am sending the `publisherId` as `String`, not sure what I am missing here.

Is the issue in the way I am creating the table, or the way I am querying?
Thanks

Comment: I would make a describeTable call on the 'Configs' to double check that the secondary index has been created as expected.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Try to change `ExpressionAttributeValues` from this

```
{ 
 TableName: 'Configs',
 IndexName: 'publisher_index',
 KeyConditionExpression: 'publisherId = :pub_id',
 ExpressionAttributeValues: { ':pub_id': { S: '700' } } 
}
```

to

```
{ 
 TableName: 'Configs',
 IndexName: 'publisher_index',
 KeyConditionExpression: 'publisherId = :pub_id',
 ExpressionAttributeValues: { ':pub_id': '700'} 
}
```

From `{ ':pub_id': { S: '700' } }` to `{ ':pub_id': '700'}`.

I had the same problem and I spent 2 days for this. The official documentation in misleading.

Comment: Sorry, I tried this but it does not work for me. When I do not provide something with the datatype, like in: { ':pub_id': { S: '700' } }, I get a validation error. Are you sure you are not talking about ExpressionAttributesNames instead of ExpressionAttributesValues?

Comment: The correct keyword is `ExpressionAttributeValues` and not AttributeS. Are you sure that your ValidationException is not dued to this little mistake? In my case I don't used the `ExpressionAttributeNames` parameter and that worked.

Comment: @gior91 Cool! This really helped me. Thanks!

Comment: @RobertOschler you're welcome! I'm surprised that after ~3 years this error is still present!!!

Comment: @gior91 Sign of the times.  Seeing the same thing in blockchain.  The platforms change so fast, the docs can't keep up or worse, there's multiple sets for multiple version, but the old docs naturally rise to the top of the search engines over the new ones due to their larger more mature link networks.

Comment: This is because when you use the `DocumentClient`, you no longer need the "S" to indicate that it's a string. Under the hood the API takes that data, but the `DocumentClient` abstracts it away from you in Node. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html

Answer (score 23):

Turns out it depends on whether you use `AWS.DynamoDB` or `AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient`.

Check the difference in the documentation:
[AWS.DynamoDB.query](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#query-property) vs.
[AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient.query](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#query-property)

In the DocumentClient the doc clearly states:

> The document client simplifies working with items in Amazon DynamoDB by abstracting away the notion of attribute values. This abstraction annotates native JavaScript types supplied as input parameters, as well as converts annotated response data to native JavaScript types.
>
> ...
>
> Supply the same parameters as AWS.DynamoDB.query() with AttributeValues substituted by native JavaScript types.

Maybe you where also referring to the [DynamoDB API Reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html#API_Query_Examples) which in fact makes no assumptions about the used SDK but uses plain HTTP Requests in the examples.

Thus using the `AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient` you would just provide a simple key-value map for `ExpressionAttributeValues` as suggested by @gior91.

Answer (score 7):

As stated above, you need to use the DynamoDB Document Client if you want to abtract away the type casting.

```
var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
```

...then you can just use the above listed object notation to call the API.

```
{ ':pub_id': '700'}
```

Ran into this issue myself, I was using DynamoDB() in some places and the docClient in others, couldn't figure it out for awhile, but that'll solve it.

Answer (score 2):

I found the other answers very helpful, but I *still* couldn't get the `ValidationException`s to go away... eventually I realized that I'd been using the `DocumentClient`'s `.get` instead of `.query`

(Technically not an answer to the question, but posting this here rather than in a comment to make it more visible to anyone else struggling with such a marvellously unhelpful error message.)

Comment: Well you actually helped me there, that was the origin of my error. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I am late, but I'd like to share a method that will guarantee a correct query param.

So,

1. go to your aws console, select dynamodb service,
2. in the left, it's the dynamodb menu and click "Explore items".
3. And then, choose the table you are interested in.
4. after selecting the table, in the right, the top will show "Scan/Query items". Please expand it
5. choose "Query" tab and in the dropdown, select your index
6. then, input a value, and click the button "Run"
7. ATTENTION: In the network of chrome, the "Fetch/XHR" tab will show a http request. Please see the payload. It's the query you need. Of course, you can try to remove some fields you don't need, such as "Limit"
8. How to use the query param? `await documentClient.query(params).promise();`

If you are still confused, see the screenshot below:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is technically not an answer to the question asked, but I am posting this here to make it visible to anyone else dealing with the validation error.

I was getting the "query condition missed key schema element id" ValidationError.

The problem was that my QueryCommand was missing "IndexName" field. After adding it, the command worked.

What helped me figure it out was the documentation - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#query-property

Answer (score -3):

Try replacing your query JSON with this:

```
{
  TableName: 'Configs',
  IndexName: 'publisher_index',
  KeyConditionExpression: '#publisherId = :pub_id',
  ExpressionAttributeNames: { '#publisherId': 'publisherId' },
  ExpressionAttributeValues: { ':pub_id': { 'S': '700' } }
}
```